# Github CLI - Grep for filtering by phrase in pull request body?

Tags: github, grep, pull-request, github-cli

I’m using the Github CLI tool, which includes a command `gh pr list` that allows you to see all the open pull requests.

The issue is that I only see a list of their titles and there’s a separate command `gh pr view [extra info]` that actually allows you to see the `body`.

I’m searching for pull requests that have a certain phrase in the BODY so `gh pr list | grep “hello”` wouldn’t work because it only gives me pull requests with `“hello”` in the header, and not necessarily the body.

How might I go about approaching this problem and are there any shortcuts in the github cli that might help me?

Comment: Here is the manual [man: gh pr view](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view). Did you explore the arguments to the `list` sub-command? Probably something like: `gh pr view --json number,title,body,reviews,assignees` ... You can use even with `--template` ( [more](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_help_formatting) )

Answer (score 0):

Sicne [`gh pr list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list), like [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view), does inherit from the same option `--json <fields>` (Output JSON with the specified fields), you can use:

```
gh pr list --json number,body | grep "helllo"
```

That would grep for your specific message, and still give you an ID that you can use with `gh pr view`.